# LinkedList modified, Thread crashing the program

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, synchronize

My problem is a synchronization problem with a thread and the user simultaneously accessing and modifying a `LinkedList`.

I’m making a program in C# that will display some messages in a panel.  I’m getting an error called “The collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated.”, that is because I’m adding or removing messages while a thread is accessing the `LinkedList`.

I have read some solutions but I am still unable to make them work.  I’m using an `Enumerator` for the thread work in my `LinkedList`.  I tried to make some locks in my code so the thread would not iterate the list while I remove or add an element. I also tried to lock the thread for the operations on my list. But all my attempts failed.

Here is some code of my project. This one is for **adding a message**:

```
public void addMsg(MsgForDisplay msg) {
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Text = (msg.getMsgText() + " -");
    lbl.ForeColor = color;
    lbl.Font = textFont;
    lbl.BackColor = backg;
    lbl.Visible = true;
    lbl.AutoSize = true;
    lbl.Location = new Point(width(), 0);
    //lock(labels) { tried to lock here but failed
        labels.AddLast(lbl);
        lastLb = lbl;
        this.Controls.Add(lbl);
        this.Refresh();
    //}
}
```

**Removing a message**:

```
public void removeMsg(string msg) {
    string remove = msg + " -";
    Label lbRemove = null;
    //lock(labels) { also tried to lock here
        var it = labels.GetEnumerator();
        while(it.MoveNext()) {
            Label label = it.Current;
            if (label.Text.Equals(remove)) {
                lbRemove = label;
            }
        }
        labels.Remove(lbRemove);
        this.Controls.Remove(lbRemove);
        this.Refresh();
    //}
}
```

And there is the problem, in **my thread**:

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        // lock (labels) { also tried to lock here
            var it = labels.GetEnumerator();
            while (it.MoveNext()) { // the crash occurs here
                Label lb = it.Current;
                if (lb.Location.X + lb.Width < 0) {
                    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { this.Controls.Remove(lb); }));
                    if (labels.Count > 1)
                        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { lb.Location = new Point(lastLb.Right, 0); }));
                    else
                        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { lb.Location = new Point(2000, 0); }));
                    lastLb = lb;
                    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { this.Controls.Add(lb); }));
                    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { this.Refresh(); }));
                }
                if (leftLb != null)
                    if (leftLb.Location.X + leftLb.Width - lb.Location.X < -20)
                        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { lb.Location = new Point(leftLb.Right, 0); }));
                    else
                        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { lb.Location = new Point(lb.Location.X - 3, lb.Location.Y); }));
                    leftLb = lb;
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30);
        // }
    }
}
```

As you can see I’m using an `GetEnumerator` of my labels, what in Java should be the `Iterator`.  With this I shouldn’t be able to iterate the list without problem when the user add or remove messages?

Is there a way to synchronize the accesses to the list?

**EDIT**: I have tried the `ConcurrentBag` and `ConcurrentDictionary` but without any improvement to the project as you can see in the comments…

Please before you post an answer read the comments bellow to make sure that you know what is going on.

**EDIT**: Tried to add a mutex to my code for `addMsg` and `removeMsg` but still crashing.  If I use the mutex in the thread it will be slowed down.

Comment: Why not try a ConcurrentQueue, a ConcurrentStack or a ConcurrentBag?

Comment: Don't do that.  It defeats the purpose of using threads.

Comment: *that is because I'm adding messages or removing while a thread is accessing the LinkedList*. **No** it is because you add/remove to the list while you are *enumerating* it.

Comment: Yes L.B, and that happens when i add or remove a message...@SLaks dont do what?  @L33Ts can you tell me what you think that is the best of them? I don't know them but I will do some research about them

Comment: Don't use threads here.  Instead, use `await`, or a WinForms timer with a queue.

Comment: ConcurrentBag is an unordered thread-safe collection ConcurrentQueue is a FIFO (First in, first out.) thread-safe collection and ConcurrentStack is a LIFO (Last in, first out.) thread-safe collectio. You can find more information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx

Comment: Thank you L33TS, I will check that out. @SLaks and with I can make my labels run in the background without my program stop? I made a thread for make the labels move while the program is running

Comment: @L33TS I'm doing it with the ConcurrentBad now but I got a problem, when I remove a message, sometimes it remove the wrong message, this might be because ConcurrentQueue isn't ordenated?

Comment: ConcurrentBag is unordered and there is no order to the elements added and retrieved. ConcurrentQueue is ordered and the first elements added will also be the first elements to be retrieved. Ex. for a CB it might be like this Add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and when retrieving them you get Retrieve(5, 3, 4, 2, 1). However with CQ it will be like this Add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and when retrieving Retrieve(1, 2, 3, 4, 5). With CS it would be like this Add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and when retrieving it would be (5, 4, 3, 2, 1).

Comment: The problem is that I need to remove an elemenent not by the order, for exemple, the user add 5 messages, (1 .. 5) and then he removes the message 3, it should remove the message 3, not the 1 or 5... I had a look on ConcurrentDictionary but it is a bit buggy, sometimes i removed a message and added again, and if i didnt wait at least 1 sec the computer would not add it to the display bar...

Comment: Most probably I am not getting the real problem here. Why do I suspect that you tried the locks individually in each method. You have to use the locks in each of your Add()/Remove()/Thread(). Only then the locks will do what you want them to do.

Comment: I used them but then I got a deadlock

Comment: -1: When posting code, spend some time to cut down the code to simplest example that breaks.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "tried to lock here but failed". How and when does it fail?

Comment: My bad. I should have noticed that :). Just move the sleep statement outside the lock  and you wont get deadlocks

Comment: I mean, that thing about the Linkedlist is done, but this still some bugs when I add a message, so I need to lock a variable that will take my lastLb (last label insert). I needto lock it on **addMsg** and at my  timer when the label gets out of the panel, but if the user add a label at the same time it is going to the end of the queue, the lastLb value got bug and the last label isn't the last or I get a deadlock, there shouldn't be a mutex for control this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a Timer in step of the thread and that solved the crashing problem. Here is the code if you want to see it.

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

private void startThread() {
    myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(timerEvent);
    myTimer.Interval = 30;
    myTimer.Start();
}

private void timerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var it = labels.GetEnumerator();

    while (it.MoveNext()) {
        Label lb = it.Current;
        // Label lb = labels.ElementAt(b);
        if (lb.Location.X + lb.Width < 0) {
            this.Controls.Remove(lb);
            if (labels.Count > 1)
                lb.Location = new Point(lastLb.Right, 0);
            else
                lb.Location = new Point(2000, 0);
            lastLb = lb;
            this.Controls.Add(lb);

            this.Refresh();
        }

        if (leftLb != null)
            if (leftLb.Location.X + leftLb.Width - lb.Location.X < -20)
                lb.Location = new Point(leftLb.Right, 0);
            else
                lb.Location = new Point(lb.Location.X - 3, lb.Location.Y);
        leftLb = lb;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The source of your problem is that while you are iterating over the list of labels You call either Remove or Add functions which modifies this list whis is not allowed while iterating over it. Instead of this

```
var it = labels.GetEnumerator();
while (it.MoveNext()) // the crash occurs here
```

I suggest something like that:

```
for(int i = 0; i < labels.Count; i++)
{
     labels.remove(labels[i]); //this is valid of course the count of the list will change
     //Here you can add or remove elements from the labels
}
```

Or you can try first to collect the removable items into a temporal list and later remove it from the original.

Comment: if you remove an item in a for loop, be sure to decrement `i`. eg. `i--;`

Comment: The problem is that a label can be removed while the thread is in the loop

Answer (score 0):

As others have already stated, the problem is you are modifying the collection while enumerating over it.

Now, the easiest workaround is obviously not to enumerate over the same collection that is being modified. And how do you do that? Simple, you just clone the collection, and iterate over it:

```
lock (labels)
{
    var clone = new LinkedList<Label>(labels);
    it = labels.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Now you can enumerate over it safely, without worrying about inconsistencies.

A few notes:

- I am using a lock, because the cloning also must enumerate over your collection, and while it does it in a very short time, it is still required for synchronization. Off course, you need to uncomment the locks you've already added to addMsg and removeMsg.
- The reason that locking your whole loop didn't work, is that when you call Invoke, you are essentially returning control to the thread that owns the object (the main GUI thread in this case). The problem is, that this thread is already stuck on handling whatever event caused addMsg or removeMsg to be called, leading to a deadlock.
- **You should also note that cloning a collection every 30 ms, isn't exactly efficient, and shouldn't be used in a production code**, but given that this probably just an exercise, it should suffice. In real life, you should probably use a separate collection for the changes you are about to do (adding or removing labels), change this collection in addMsg and removeMsg, and then merge the changes to labels inside your thread, but outside of the iteration over the labels.
- Not directly related to your question, but still: you should use a foreach loop instead of directly creating an enumerator object in C#.

Comment: You don't want to lock on `labels`. Have a separate, non-mutable object of which the sole purpose is to act as a lock.

Answer (score 0):

As stated before, changing any collection while enumerating it, results in an exception in .Net. You can avoid this by using for or while loops.

However I don't see the point in using a Linked List in this scenario. It should be way simpler and more performant to use a ConcurrentDictionary and just add or remove the requested item. There is also a ObservableConcurrentDictionary available, although not part of the Framework. It is very stable, in my experience.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/208361/Concurrent-Observable-Collection-Dictionary-and-So